# Fade effect of nivo slider

Tags: slider, fade, nivo-slider

my slider does not work properly when i use Fade effect. But with another effect, everything is fine.

Now, i am using Fade effect : But the picture change position every time. If i click to second Dot, the picture does not change : 
http://mmafitness.com.au/home

But if i use another effect. Example fold. It's working quite good. 
http://mmafitness.com.au/test-slider-3

I can not find out why. Please, help me!

Comment: it's not that it doesn't work entirely, it just seems to miss the first click...